# The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory for content folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem where this path

```
http://localhost:20131/Content/Images/landingpages/
```

causes a 403 error in the console tab of the chrome browser. The image in landing pages does load ok, but I want to get rid of the error.

if I try to load the path itself in the browser then I get

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I used the directoryBrowsing=true in web.config but I don't want ALL my files browsable like scripts etc as that is very unsecure.

Is there a way to limit directory browsing for just the Images folder?
I have a feeling that is what staticContent is for but that seems to just be for mimeTypes..

The error in the browser occurs when I display the image like this

```
<div class="img" style="background-image: url('/Content/Images/landingpages/{{LandingController.navigationData.pictureUrl}}');"></div>
```

but not like this

```
 <img style="width:100%;height:80%" src="/Content/Images/landingpages/{{NewPaymentController.navigationData.pictureUrl}}" />
```

I have no idea why that is...

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7 or newer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <configuration>  
            <location path="." allowOverride="True">
               <system.webServer>
                    <directoryBrowse enabled="True" />
               </system.webServer>
            </location>
        </configuration>
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/directorybrowse

Comment: This allows all the scripts to load though, I only want to allow the content/images folder

Comment: @LukeP unfortunately that is not supported by default.  You could write your own.  Mike V has a nice one here:  http://mvolo.com/get-nice-looking-directory-listings-for-your-iis-website-with-directorylistingmodule/

Comment: That is just to display the listing as icons?

Comment: @LukeP in his case, yes.  But you could filter based on the file extension so that you only list the file extensions you allow.  `string[] allowed = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif" }`... `if (allowed.contains(filename)) { //code here to show file }`